# Looking for proof/derivation for non-zero off-diagonal terms in density matrix as a characterization of interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, decoherence, foundations

Is anyone capable of giving a rigorous derivation of why non-zero off-diagonal terms in the density matrix of a quantum system written in a spesific observable basis characterize the possibility of interference phenomena in said basis?

Or alternatively, does anyone know a source (an article or book) where this proof/derivation is performed?

I have read the following books, but they contain no satisfying answer:

- Schlosshauer, Decoherence and the quantum to classical transition
- Ballentine, Quantum Mechanics
- Schwabel, Quantum Mechanics
- Liboff, Quantum Mechanics

Of these Schlosshauer is the only one who examines this question at all, he does it for a bipartite composite system (see the screenshots)[image]

[image]

As can be seen from the second screenshot he ends the treatment by referring to an earlier mention, but unfortunately in this earlier mention ("Sect. 2.4.2") he just states the claim for a general system without proof.

This omission raises the question in the reader's mind: can this claim be derived for a general system or is his argument actually a circular argument, where it can only be shown for a bipartite system entangled with the environment with orthogonal states, as done in the first screen shot?

Thank you in advance for your help and comments!

Edit: The screen shots are there because they are not relevant to the question. Rather they illustrate and provide background to the question.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: This is pretty much a matter of understanding how one defines the density matrix and interference. Note that density matrix is a generalization of wave function - if you understand what interference is in terms of wave function, it should be not difficult to get it for the density matrix (e.g., one could consider how interference arises in two-slit experiment or Stern-Gerlach device).

Comment: I will send you again to https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/ and associated discussion, as it seems its contents has not had much effect on you yet.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The screen shots are in no way essential for the question, I am not asking anyone to explain his argument or anything like that. I could have easily just added a link, then none of these comments would have occured. The more I think of this the more the screen shots feel justified, even after reading the content of the link you posted.

Comment: well... I'm not the only one reminding you of this for this question, and regrettably for you your question has attracted 3 downvotes, no doubt in part because of the screenshots.  If you think the screenshots are inessential, then surely you can edit you post to focus on the essential, including a digest of the argument without the screenshot.

Comment: Why do you expect people to answer your question if you don't take the time to properly edit and format your question such that it fits the site and community rules?!

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I don't mind the downvotes but of course I don't want to intentionally go against rules of conduct. But I feel that I am not doing so, since I am stating everything essential in words in the question.

Comment: @user339529 look... your question is a reasonable question and this site *needs* reasonable questions, but if you look at the feedbacks it seems clear you should invest a bit of time in editing your question, to the benefit of all.  It will become entirely searchable, and will show you actually thought about the essential points of your post.

Comment: I think this was a good question, hopefully it is not closed. I remember being confused by this also.

Answer (score 2):

Much here depends on how one defines *interference* - under some definitions this is a non-question, since interference is defined in terms of wave function, of which the density matrix is a generalization.

Let us consider, e.g., an interference experiment, in which a particle finds itself in one of two states, $|1\rangle, |2\rangle$ with probability amplitudes $a_1, a_2$, that is
$$
|\psi\rangle = a_1|1\rangle + a_2|2\rangle.
$$
If we consider a simple version of the two-slit experiment, the probability amplitudes are $a_n=e^{ikL_n}$, and the interference picture arises from considering
$$|a_1+a_2|^2=|a_1|^2+|a_2|^2+2\Re[a_1^*a_2]=2+2\Re\left[e^{ik(L_1-L_2)}\right]$$
The last term in the equations above is the *interference* - it is not precisely defined, but it is intuitively understood what it means here.

In our basis $|1\rangle,|2\rangle$ the measurement operator can be written as
$$
\Omega=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
so that
$\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle=|a_1|^2+|a_2|^2+2\Re[a_1^*a_2]
$.

We now can rewrite the above in terms of a density matrix for a pure state:
$$
\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\begin{bmatrix}|a_1|^2&a_1^*a_2\\a_1 a_2^*&|a_2|^2\end{bmatrix},$$
in which case the measurement is expressed as
$$ 
\langle \Omega\rangle=\text{tr}\left[\rho\Omega\right]=|a_1|^2+|a_2|^2+2\Re[a_1^*a_2]$$

In terms of an arbitrary density matrix the same result takes form
$$ 
\langle \Omega\rangle=\text{tr}\left[\rho\Omega\right]=\rho_{11}+\rho_{22}+2\Re[\rho_{12}]$$
Identifying $\rho_{11},\rho_{22}$ as probabilities to be found in states $1,2$ (i.e., $|a_1|^2,|a_2|^2$ in the pure state case) we are left with identifying $2\Re[\rho_{12}]$ as the interference contribution (analogous to $2\Re[a_1^*a_2]$ in the pure case).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see your argument and the general principle seems sound.<br/>  So basically if I understand correctly, when calculating expectation values everything which is different compared to a classical ensemble is deemed to be a result of "interference". And the terms in the density matrix that cause this are deemed "interference terms".

Comment: @user339529 yes, I think there's really no more to it. Interference is just adding waves - it is not really a quantum mechanical notion. Perhaps, yiu could look for *degree of coherence* in quantum optics, e.g., in Glauber's nobel lecture.

Comment: Thank you for the reference tip, I'll check it out, one never knows. I think your answer is very likely to be the definitive one - comparing the situation to the classical case and then just labeling what is different with a loose term sounds very much like what physicists tend to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's define what we exactly mean by "interference phenomena". The way I see it, interference and superposition go hand in hand. If I call the specific observable basis you mention $\{\vert n\rangle\}$, I see any state
$$\vert \psi \rangle = \sum_{n} \alpha_n \vert n \rangle,\tag{1}$$
as a state generated by the interference of the $\vert n\rangle$ states for which $\alpha_n \neq 0$. E.g., the single-qubit state $\vert \psi \rangle = (\vert 0 \rangle + \vert 1 \rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ is generated by the interference of the $\vert 0 \rangle$ and $\vert 1 \rangle$ basis states. Similarly, for a single particle in 1D, the wavefunction $\psi(x) \propto e^{-i p_1 x/\hbar} + e^{-i p_2 x/\hbar}$ is an interference between two momentum eigenstates with eigenvalues $p_1$ and $p_2$. If we go by this definition of interference, it's straightforward to see why this would correspond to the off-diagonal elements of a density matrix in said basis.

To see this, let's first write the the density matrix in terms of a statistical ensemble of pure states $\rho = \sum_k p_k \vert \psi_k \rangle \langle\psi_k\vert$. The matrix elements in the $\{\vert n\rangle\}$ basis are
$$\rho_{nm} = \sum_k p_k \langle n \vert\psi_k\rangle\langle\psi_k\vert m \rangle.\tag{2}$$
Now, using a similar decomposition to $(1)$,  if I write $\vert\psi_k\rangle = \sum_{n}\alpha_n^{(k)}\vert n \rangle$, I see that
$$\rho_{nm} = \sum_k \alpha_n^{(k)} \alpha_m^{(k)*}. \tag{3}$$
Looking at the off-diagonal elements $n\neq m$, it's easy to see that $\rho_{nm} \neq 0$ only if at least one of the pure states $\vert \psi_k\rangle$ in the ensemble has more than one non-zero $\alpha_n^{(k)}$ coefficient, meaning that -- by the above definition -- it is a result of some eigenstates "interfering" with each other.

Hence, non-zero off-diagonal elements of a density matrix signify the existence of interference effects between the corresponding basis states.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My comment to your answer was hopelessly too long so I posted it as a separate answer. If you have time please check it and comment on it.